# Error : while write a table into the datawarehouse in databricks after blob storage upgrade to azure data lake

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I am trying to write a table into the data warehouse via a python script in databricks after the blob storage upgrade to azure data lake, below is the error and lines of code

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4178246062441208> in <module>
    271 
    272 
--> 273   feature_importance_table.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")\
    274 .option("tableOptions","heap,distribution=ROUND_ROBIN")\
    275 .option("url", url)\`
Caused by: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, https://jaidiroblb01.dfs.core.windows.net/ja-idiro-cnt-01/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:237
```

Code

```
feature_importance_table.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")\
.option("tableOptions","heap,distribution=ROUND_ROBIN")\
.option("url", url)\
.option("tempDir", "abfss://ja-idiro-cnt-01@jaidiroblb01.dfs.core.windows.net/")\
.option("useAzureMSI", "true")\
.option("dbtable", y+".TMP_PYTHON_JOB4")\
.option("append","true")\
.option("user", "<Sql User>")\
.option("password", "<Password>").save()'
```

I am guessing the service principle would need a Storage Blob Data Contributor role seeing that the environment has been changed from private to public?

Comment: Those aren't your real connection details in the screenshot, are they?

Comment: If they are, delete the question and re-ask with masked credentials. Otherwise, they are viewable in the edit history

Answer (score 0):

To resolve

> Caused by: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to
> perform this operation.", 403, HEAD,
> [https://jaidiroblb01.dfs.core.windows.net/ja-idiro-cnt-01/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90]
> at
> shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:237`

this error, try either of the following ways:

**1.Set the Access Token provider**

> spark.conf.set("spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName", "") spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type",
> "com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider")
> df =
> [spark.read.csv('abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/<DIRECTORY](mailto:spark.read.csv('abfss://%3cCONTAINER%3e@%3cACCOUNT%3e.dfs.core.windows.net/%3cDIRECTORY)
> PATH>')   df.show()

**2.Edit the Spark Config by entering the connection information for your Azure Storage account**

> spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.[blob.core.windows.net](http://blob.core.windows.net/)
> <ACCESS_KEY>, where <STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME> is your Azure Storage
> account name, and <ACCESS_KEY> is your storage access key.

Example:

> [spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.bigdatalabstore.blob.core.windows.net](http://spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.bigdatalabstore.blob.core.windows.net/)
> HD+91Y77b+TezEu1lh9QXXU2Va6Cjg9bu0RRpb/KtBj8lWQa6jwyA0OGTDmSNVFr8iSlkytIFONEHLdl67Fgxg==

References: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/notebook-this-request-is-not-authorized-to-perform-this/ba-p/1712566 , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/388994/azure-databricks-adf-connectivity-issue-delta-tabl.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/25915/azure-databricks-throwing-403-error.html